# ToolStripProfessionalRenderer for Visual Studio 2008 Look-and-Feel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface, themes

I came across this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/menus/Office2007Renderer.aspx) today that offers a ToolStripProfessionalRenderer implementation for the Office 2007 look-and-feel.

From what I can tell, it would be fairly straightforward (albeit tedious) to customize this to support various other themes, such as the silver and black themes of Office 2007.

More specifically, I'd like to find a color table that matches Visual Studio 2008.  Does anyone know where I might find this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this a while back, and even have a bookmark for it: http://blogs.msdn.com/jfoscoding/articles/489637.aspx

I think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: That's almost exactly what I'm looking for.  I added the color table from your link to the Office2007Renderer project and used it instead of the default Office2007ColorTable.  It's awfully close and gets me much further down the road!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, tedious.  You can find color settings in the MFC Feature Pack files, included with VS2008 SP1.  There are 4 Office themes, they each have a style.xml file in a subdirectory of vc/atlmfc/include.  Black, Blue, Silver and Aqua.

Answer (score 0):

I posted about Office 2007 style when I was doing WinForms.

http://www.lextm.com/index.php/2008/02/office-2007-style/

Although Krypton does not ship a Visual Studio 2008 style, you should be able to customize as it is highly flexible.